# Compress two Dir.glob to if - else

Tags: ruby

Actually i'm trying to compress that Dir.glob to one if-then.

```
Dir.glob('*.ogg') do |ogg_file|
testfile = ogg_file
filename = File.basename(testfile,File.extname(testfile))
end
# Submethod for searching for *.m4a files
Dir.glob('*.m4a') do |m4a_file|
testfile = m4a_file
filename = File.basename(testfile,File.extname(testfile))
end
```

Can anyone help me to do that, so it returns just one variable "filename"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I can :

```
Dir.glob('*.{ogg,m4a}') do |file|
  filename = File.basename(file, File.extname(file))
end
```

[Dir::glob](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob) says :

> `{p,q}` - Matches either literal `p` or literal `q`. Equivalent to pattern alternation in regexp. Matching literals may be more than one character in length. More than two literals may be specified.

Comment: Thanks :-) Easier than i thought